# Is it possible to forward a get request using nginx proxy to the same url with port

Tags: ajax, nginx, url-rewriting, proxy

I have a simple python bottle api, and a nginx server that host the index.html that makes ajax request to the bottle api running on the local host on port 8001. The problem is I don't handle the CORS because its running in a closed env and its just a simple api to manage some active directory stuff and it sits behind a firewall and basic auth. I'm not really worried about cross site scripting. What I need to know is if I program my ajax request from

```
                $.ajax({ 
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "http://localhost:8001/newuser/" + "firstName=" + fname + "&lastName=" + lname + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + new_password,
                   success: function(data){        
                     alert(data);
                     document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = data.toString();
                   }
                });
```

to

```
                $.ajax({ 
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "/newuser/" + "firstName=" + fname + "&lastName=" + lname + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + new_password,
                   success: function(data){        
                     alert(data);
                     document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = data.toString();
                   }
                });
```

how do I write the nginx rewrite to take the ajax request and make it goto port 8001 at local host, and if thats even possible. I looked at a few examples but couldn't quite find what I needed.

Can someone help me with the nginx code for this, I need to forward the request to localhost at :8001 and not :80 when /newuser/ is detected.

This is because when I call localhost:8001 it gives me a cors error in the web console.

I tried to disable CORS in nginx

nginx config

```
location * {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

}
```

virtual nginx config

```
    location * {
         if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            #
            # Om nom nom cookies
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';


 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution I figured it out.

```
#
# A virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#

upstream admanager.oneplatform.build {
    server localhost:8001;
}

server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root /opt/admanager1;
        index index.html;

        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        location /newuser/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/newuser/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /update/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/update/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

}
```